# Trouble with audio playback

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

The layout of project architecture:

record audio -> trim audio -> play trimmed audio -> upload to server.

I'm having troubles with playback of audio file that is created as a result of AVAssetExportSession trimming. I had doubts about integrity of trimmed file and I've uploaded it to server and there it plays fine, but iOS refuses to play it. I init AVAudioPlayer with URL to trimmed file, then play() and nothing happens, not even errors are thrown.

Please see code below, what can cause the problem?

```
  static func outputFileURL() -> URL {

    let outputFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.path.appending("/audioRecord-trimmed.m4a")
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFileURL)

  }


@IBAction func trimRecording(_ sender: RoundCornerButton) {

    //Delete existing recording
    deleteEditedRecording()

    //Check duration
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(recordingToTrim.duration)

    if (duration < 5.0) {

      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Sound is too short", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

      let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

      alertController.addAction(action)

      self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

      return

    } else {

      let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: recordingToTrim, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)

      exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A

      exporter?.outputURL = EditorVC.outputFileURL()

      exporter?.timeRange = durationToTrim!

      exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {

        if exporter?.status == .completed {

          let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

          let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

          alertController.addAction(action)

          self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

          let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: exporter?.error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

          let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

          alertController.addAction(action)

          self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

          print(exporter?.error?.localizedDescription)

          print("Export failed")

          return
        }

      })
    }

  }

@IBAction func playTrimmedAudio(_ sender: RoundCornerButton) {

    print("\nPlay tap\n")

    let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: EditorVC.outputFileURL())
    player.play()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare audio player globally like this :

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer!
```

in your playTrimmedAudio function add this two line of code

```
player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: EditorVC.outputFileURL())
player.play()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a fix! Could you explain why it fixes the issue?

Comment: It has to do with ARC in the sense that your AVAudioPlayer is getting deallocated right after you instantiate it, because with ARC local variables are deallocated when you leave the scope